# Best book or documentary related to mindfulness

Tags: vipassana, mindfulness, books

What is your best mindfulness book or documentary? I have experienced Vipassana retreats. I would like to know more about mindfulness.

Comment: I would recommend Ajahn Brahms 'Mindfulness, Bliss and Beyond'...

Answer (score 1):

Most Buddhists don't know what mindfulness is therefore i cannot recall any good books about it except a short talk by Bhikkhu Buddhadasa called [The Use of Dhamma](http://dhammatalks.net/Books/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Natural_Cure_for_Spiritual_Disease2.htm).

Pra Payutto wrote a lengthy book called [Sammasati:
An Exposition of Right Mindfulness](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Payutto_Bhikkhu_Sammasati.htm#Role) however it contains errors, such as the following:

> It is attentive, as if keeping its eyes on each impression that
> passes into consciousness and then **bearing down** on it. When one wishes
> to concentrate on a particular object, it **maintains one's attention**
> fixedly upon it, not allowing the object to drift away or disappear.
> By means of sati, one **keeps placing the mind on the object**, or
> **recollecting it**, not allowing oneself to let it slip from the mind.
> There is a simile likening it to a pillar, because it is firmly
> embedded in its object, or to a gate-keeper, because it watches over
> the various sense-doors through which sense-data pass, inspecting all
> that enters. **The proximate cause for the arising of sati is a firm and
> clear perception of the object** [OMG!], or any of the different sorts of
> satipatthana that will be spoken of below.

I recommend to read the scriptures, namely:

1. [Indriya-Vibhanga Sutta: Analysis of the Mental Faculties](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.010.than.html).
2. [SN 46.3 - Sila Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.3/en/bodhi).
3. [Maha-cattarisaka Sutta: The Great Forty](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html).
4. [Nagara Sutta: The Fortress](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/an/an07/an07.063.than.html).

In summary, "mindfulness" means "*to bring to mind (to recollect), to remember & to not forget*" to practise the Dhamma teachings. Mindfulness does not mean to observe objects.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpCy9Tb73gw) called "Buddhist Meditation: Sati Sampajanna" by Ajahn Jayasāro is reasonably good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read Satipathana Sutta and Anapanasati Sutta?
Have you watched Goenka's ten-day vipassana video series?

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.22.0.than.html

https://youtu.be/aeqCeU8Abng

Answer (score 0):

I really like the "Discourses of The Buddha", they talk a lot about mindfulness and that without a chance of misrepresenting the teacher's message.

I also like the "Book of analysis; Vibhanga" and "Enumeration of Phenomena; Dhammasanghani". They are included in the collection of books called Theravadin Abhidhamma.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Thích Nhất Hạnh's books are about mindfulness, as in, what you can do and should do to achieve mindfulness. A popular one in NA is "[Peace is Every Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553351397)", but you can just randomly choose one of his books since they are not that different from each other. They share the same message and often use the same set of anecdotes to convey the message. Hạnh tends to employ abstract imagery from nature to make examples, which can be off-putting to people who'd prefer a more concrete approach.